# How to easily reproject OpenTopoMap?

Tags: coordinate-system, basemap, opentopomap

For a web GIS application, we need to get all of our data and basemaps in the same projection.

We would like to use OpenTopoMap basemap which is in Web Mercator projection (EPSG 3857) but for our web GIS app, it has to be in Lambert93 (EPSG 2154).

How is it possible to reproject OpenTopoMap easily, if possible, with open source solution to create my own webservice of OpenTopoMap in Lambert93?

Comment: Are you talking about server side or client side reprojection? For client side OpenLayers (https://openlayers.org/) can do that without problems.

Comment: No, from client side, it can't reproject (it's another client from OpenLayers), so I have to found another way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Except with OpenLayers, I don't know about out of the box solutions to consume Spherical Mercator tiles and display them with another projection.

You should use Mapproxy https://mapproxy.org (a server side solution) to consume the tiles and serve them while reprojecting them. You can make WMS calls and behind the scene, the tool will stitch the tiles